# Critical gKdV - tutorial

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, textbook-recommendation, blow-ups

I'm looking for a good introduction to the critical generelized KdV equation
$$u_t +u_{xxx}+5u^4u_x = 0 \, , $$
$$ u(t=0,x) = u_0 (x) \, , \qquad x\in \mathbb{R} \, ,$$
and its blowup solutions. There are some [papers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4624.pdf) on the topic, but I'm looking for more of an overview - lecture notes, video, book chapter or a review.

Any ideas?

Comment: Typo in equation: last term should read $5u^4u_x$.

Answer (score 1):

How about this lecture by Yvan Martel - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ynK-udMZh0?

Comment: Tough resolution of the blackboard, but I'll give it a try. Thanks!